# Drawing to canvas always has blurry results

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have searched many web pages and throughout Stackoverflow and have not yet found an answer to my problem. I want to make a simple tile editor which will require me to be able to edit a canvas pixel by pixel. Each tile will be 8px by 8px. I have my HTML properties and CSS to use the 8 by 8 pixels. I have tried the below method and I have tried other various methods including html2canvas. I always get blurry results. Here is some test code that reproduces this problem.

[image]

I am testing with a Chromebook (Toshiba Chromebook 2) on the latest stable release. I have also tested with a Nexus 7 (2013) tablet and a LG G3 Android cell phone all with the same results. I am using the Chrome browser on each device.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {background:white;}
    </style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        drawPixel('canvas0', 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel('canvas0', 0, 1, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel('canvas0', 0, 2, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel('canvas0', 0, 3, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel('canvas0', 0, 4, 255, 0, 0, 255);

        function drawPixel (canvasname, x, y, r, g, b, a) {
            // console.log('values passed to drawPixel:', canvas, x, y, r, g, b, a);
            var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasname);
            var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
            var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5) ;
            var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

            var index = ((x + y) * canvasWidth) * 4;
            console.log('1',canvasData);
            canvasData.data[index + 0] = r;
            canvasData.data[index + 1] = g;
            canvasData.data[index + 2] = b;
            canvasData.data[index + 3] = a;
            console.log('2',canvasData);

            ctx.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas0" width="8" height="8" style="width:8px;height:8px;"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

UPDATED CODE BELOW

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {background:white;}
    </style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas0');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

        drawPixel(ctx, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel(ctx, 0, 1, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel(ctx, 0, 2, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel(ctx, 0, 3, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        drawPixel(ctx, 0, 4, 255, 0, 0, 255);

        function drawPixel(ctx, x, y, r, g, b, a) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b  + "," + a + ")";
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas0" width="8" height="8" style="width:8px;height:8px;"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite the drawPixel method to just draw a pixel. There is no need to use ImageData objects here, and transforms doesn't work with that in any case.

My suggestion would be to do this (preserving the signature):

```
 function drawPixel (canvasname, x, y, r, g, b, a) {
     // these should in parent or global scope, just pass in the context
     var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasname);
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

     // set color, note alpha here is a value in the range [0, 1]
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + (a / 255) + ")";
     ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

To make the pixel sharper, use the translate (and only once) in global scope, for example (a non-signature compatible version):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("test");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

drawPixel(ctx, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255);
drawPixel(ctx, 0, 1, 255, 0, 0, 255);
drawPixel(ctx, 0, 2, 0, 255, 0, 255); // to show more clearly
drawPixel(ctx, 0, 3, 255, 0, 0, 255);
drawPixel(ctx, 0, 4, 255, 0, 0, 255);

// show image with standard interpolation (bilinear)
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 8, 8,   8, 0, 64, 64);

// show image enlarged using nearest-neighbor
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 8, 8,   50, 0, 64, 64);

function drawPixel(ctx, x, y, r, g, b, a) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + (a / 255) + ")";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width=130 height=64></canvas>
```

Additionally, you can remove the style attribute inside the tag. The canvas element will adopt to the size given as width/height.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know to put this at the global scope. I've changed my code to match what you provided and fixed the missing '+' after the 'b'. Results are the same. I have added the new code in it's entirety to my question just for clarity.

Comment: @Nicksen782 ops, my bad on the translate. This works with lines, but for fillRect it's better not to use it. Added live demo - seems sharp now.

Comment: I added a link to the image because I cannot upload images yet. I commented out the translate line. The results are sharper but not blocky like pixels.

Comment: @Nicksen782 that image is not 8x8..? If you enlarge a 8x8 image to something bigger the result will usually be blurry. However, if you do this inside canvas you can turn off interpolation (or rather, use nearest-neighbor). Let me update answer with an example.

Comment: @Nicksen782 hope this helps! Good luck with the project.

Comment: I have integrated the new code into my project and it works as expected and changing the CSS scales the image properly. So, canvas and context should be global? Was that the ultimate problem? Thank you very much, Ken.

Comment: @Nicksen782 it's mostly for performance, a single canvas and context can be shared with the entire project. Every time querySelector or getElementById etc. is used, it has to look up the whole DOM tree to find it. It's better to "cache" it in a variable and reuse that. But there is no rule saying you can't do it other ways either.. :)